# Access control over multiple cvs source code repositories

Tags: git, svn, cvs

We have a server which stores the source code of multiple projects using CVS.

The issue is that once a person is granted an account for the server, he can check out all the repositories. How can we enforce some simple access control, so that an account can only access specified repositories?

Is SVN or GIT easier to enforce such access control?

Comment: Which OS are you running on the server?

Comment: To Yannick: Red Hat Enterprise Linux server 5.4. The machine is under the control of IT people, who usually only accept simple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to manage access to your projects using the server's user management...

You can have several repositories and several user groups. Then you grant access to the groups you want on the repositories (that are folder on the server). Finally, you will just have to add people to groups to achieve the user control you want.

Answer (score 0):

Git is file based, so if a user has access to the files in a git tracked folder, then they have access to the git repo. I would recommend using git, and managing the user access level by using the features of the server to handle file-based user level access.